# Calculate share based on other column values

Tags: sql, presto

I would like to calculate the share of total orders for a given country while also showing the country column.

Sample output:

| customer_id | country | count_orders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20323 | GB | 43 |
| 20323 | US | 94 |

Expected output:

| customer_id | country | count_orders | share_total_orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20323 | GB | 43 | 0.313 |
| 20323 | US | 94 | 0.686 |

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option is using the `SUM` window function to catch your total orders:

```
SELECT customer_id, 
       country, 
       count_orders, 
       count_orders / SUM(count_orders) OVER() AS share_total_orders
FROM orders
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cross join on the sum of all the orders and divide by it:

```sql
SELECT     customer_id, country, count_orders, 
           count_orders / total_orders AS share_total_orders
FROM       orders
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(count_orders) AS total_orders
            FROM   orders) s
```